# Service Cloud Migration - Merging 2 orgs

Tags: servicecloud, org

I would like to know if anybody has experience merging 2 service cloud orgs, the key factors to consider, the impact and the steps. I found a couple of links online that outlines the steps, but I wanted to check if anyone has realtime experience and can provide an insight. I am completely new to this and will be managing the merger project and need to come up with a detailed plan and present it soon.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a related question about org consolidation with some details for you to consider: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/119/660

Comment: I did a merge of a Sales Cloud org into a Sales + Service Clouds org. The process is quite org dependent. You need a thorough understanding of both data models and the customizations in the two orgs, and it's tough to make generic recommendations.

Comment: @David Reed, Thank you for the tips. Do you have any documentation that you have related to that? Would be really helpful. I can provide my email id. Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any public documentation (like I said, it's extremely org specific). In my case, the details would largely be confidential.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenges you'll have to face if you are looking forward to merging 2 service cloud orgs are both technical and business-oriented (which should have been scoped/refactored in a previous study):

**TL;DR:** There will be a need to review similarities and differences between everything used in their day-to-day business like SLA, support processes, case channels (email-to-case, web-to-case), knowledge articles, milestones, holidays, specific developments, governors limit (outbound emails per day), storage usage, legacy service console VS lightning service console, data migration matters, etc...

=> Merging two service cloud heterogeneous orgs implies to review everything that is used in each org, if they can be merged or kept, if they impact a functionnality or another one ([service cloud cookbook might help you list all](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/support.pdf)).
Sometimes, starting from a brand new org from scratch can be wiser than trying to put a a mammoth in a small swimming pool.

**Examples:**

- Heterogeneous and similarities between support processes of the 2 orgs. In other words, you'll need to find out if 2 supports processes cover the same need and whether you need to merge them into one
- Milestone management and their associated actions/end dates. This impacts also the business hours and holidays you might have to merge
- Assignment rules, escalation rules, teams
- Web-to-case, email-to-case, auto-response rules
- Governors limits like for instance the number of outbound emails per day
- Data Migration and associated transformations if needed to fit the target org
- [...]

Comment: I do not see anything related to merge process in the cook book, can you please point out the location? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaSkyWalker I didn't express myself clearly :  merging processes is not a feature described in the cookbook but is part of the cleaning/refactoring/merging you have to do when merging two orgs. Let's say if org1 has a a logic A=>B=>C and org2 has A'=>B=>C' you might want to factor it to (A | A') => B => (C | C'). The idea is to get a decent destination org that answers to the business need, fits in governor's limits and that is decent to customize/develop on instead of some tentacular copy => paste => merge of org1 and 2.